# How to search data in mongodb with dynamic fields using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've a node.js api in which user sends the required fields as an array to be fetched from the mongodb database. I need to find the data of that fields using Find query. I've written forEach statement to loop through that array and got the array elements. But when I try to get the results by inserting the array elements in the query, it doesn't giving the required results. Could any one please help me in resolving the issue by seeing the code below?

```
templateLevelGraphData: async function(tid,payload){
    let err, templateData, respData = [], test, currentValue;
    [err,templateData] = await to(Template.findById(tid));
    var templateId = templateData.templateId;

    payload.variables.forEach(async data=>{
           console.log(data); //data has the array elements like variables=["humidity"]
           [err, currentValue] = await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(templateId).find({},{data:1}).sort({"entryDayTime":-1}).limit(1).toArray());
           console.log(currentValue);
    });
    return "success";
}
```

The expected output is,

```
[ { humidity: 36 } ]
```

But I'm getting only `_id` like,

```
 [ { _id: 5dce3a2df89ab63ee4d95495 } ]
```

I think `data` is not applying in the query. But I'm printing the data in the console where it's giving the correct results by displaying the array elements like, `humidity`. What I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got the solution.

```
for(let i=0;i<payload.variables.length;i++){
     var test = '{"'+ payload.variables[i] +'":1,"_id":0}';
     var query = JSON.parse(test);            
     [err, currentValue] = await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(templateId).find({"deviceId":deviceId},query).sort({"entryDayTime":-1}).limit(1).toArray());
     console.log(currentValue);  //It's giving the solution
     }
```

Comment: But you are making a DB call every iteration of the loop, that's a very bad practice. Imagine you have 1000 variables in the payload, you are going to call 1000 times to the DB for one execution, your performance could burn down, and you could burnt your database.

Comment: Yeah you right. I didn't think of it. But is there any other way to achieve the solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing {data: 1}  you are passing an array where is expecting name of column.
You have to create an object where the keys are going to be the elements of the array and set them to 1.

```
const projection = data.reduce((a,b) => (a[b]=1, a), {});
[...]   .find({}, projection)     [...]
```

Comment: Am not passing an array. Am just passing a string. I tried to see the datatype of ```data``` using ```typeof data``` and it displayed as STRING.

Comment: console.log(data); //data has the array elements like variables=["humidity"]

Comment: In your comment it says that data is an array of elements. If it is an array like an string, you should parse into array first:   JSON.parse(data)

Comment: when I tried to display the data in the console, for each iteration of forEach loop, it displays each item of array. Like, ```humidity``` and in the next iterarion ```heat```. ```data``` is not in the type of array as you mentioned in the previous comment like, ```["humidity"]```

Comment: Thanks @David Vicente for your help.